# Properties and fields should be marked as ProtoMember?

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

Hi I am new to Protobuf.

I want to serialize a certain information to a byte[] send it throw a channel and I want to have access to that original information "on the other side".

Simple Code example:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class HttpTunnelResponse
{
  [ProtoMember(1)]
  private HttpStatusCode statusCode;

  public HttpTunnelResponse(HttpStatusCode statusCode)
  {
     this.statusCode = statusCode;
  }

  [ProtoMember(2)]
  public HttpStatusCode StatusCode
  {
     get
     {
        return statusCode;
     }
  }
}
```

Which objects do I have to define as ProtoMember?
Only private/public fields? 
Do I also need to make all the properties as ProtoMember?

I am kinda rooky at this, so if you know some good tutorial to explain Protobuf serialization/deserialization I would be glad.

Answer (score 0):

Public properties with a public getter can be ProtoMembers as long as the field is auto-generated. The following will work.

```
[ProtoMember(1)]
public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; }
```

If the getter is pointing somewhere else, like in your case, you have to set the private field as a proto member. The following will work.

```
[ProtoMember(1)]
private HttpStatusCode statusCode;

public HttpStatusCode StatusCode => statusCode;
```

Not all the fields/properties need to be proto members. If there's a property that only takes a value from another and show a different result it can be ignore by using a special attribute. Like so.

```
[ProtoIgnore]
public string Text => $"Status: {StatusCode}";
```

As for the tutorials, try to search the internet. A general ones like [this one](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/serialization-and-deserialization-ib-c-sharp-using-protobuf-dll/) (randomly selected from the search results) might not provide all the answers but you shouldn't be afraid to play around and see what works and what doesn't. Then look for specifics.